# JQuery Posting to WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

Receiving the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when posting JSON data to the below WCF Service.

My guess is the employee object isn't initialised but I'm unsure where that should be done as when I used a string a test it worked just fine.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Interface (IAccount.cs):

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "AccountService")]   
public interface IAccountService
    {        
        [OperationContract, WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string CreateAccount(Employee employee);        
    }

[DataContract]
    public class Employee
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string firstName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string lastName {get; set;}

}
```

Implementation (AccountService.svc)

```
AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class AccountService: IAccountService
    {
        public string CreateAccount(Employee employee)
        {
            string test = employee.firstName;

            return test;
        }
    }
```

JSON Post Data:

{"firstName":"Test","lastName":"User"}

Comment: Can you debug the service?  Do you know where the error is occurring?

Comment: Ran a server trace and it appears the reason its not working is because it's trying to use XML to decode the JSON string. The error reported in the trace is: An unrecognized element was encountered in the XML during deserialization which was ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK finally sorted this out, hopefully this helps someone with the same issue.

My initial JSON looked correct but doesn't work:{"firstName":"Test","lastName":"User"}. But by looking at the server trace you can see the inbuilt XML DeSerializer cannot map the elements to the object in the WCF Service method (employee object in my case) and this is the cause of the null reference error.

Putting the form attributes inside an object that matches the name of the service parameter however did the trick: {"employee":{"firstName":"test"}}

Answer (score 0):

By default, WebGet's RequestFormat is set to XML. Set it to Json.

Comment: Not sure I follow you, the service is marked as being JSON and I'm posting JSON data: $.ajax({ type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/AccountService.svc/CreateAccount",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json"
        });